# border in css not fitting according to div

Tags: html, css

I want to add simply a red border across the `#cont` but whenever i float these three boxes the border does not work and it only comes on top not wrapping all the div.however i can use ***overflow:auto.*** it works but i just wanted to know why it does not work with out overflow.

**HTML:**

```
<div id ="cont">
    <div class ="box" > box1 </div>
    <div class ="box" > box2 </div>
    <div class ="box" > box3 </div>
</div>
<div id="foo">footer</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cont {
  width:950px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:orange;
  float:left;       
}
#foo {
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  clear:both;
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the link to your jsfiddle so we can tweek it

Comment: you need a [clearfix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)

Comment: @Raheel Provide the link

Comment: Just add  `display:table;` to the parent (`#cont`).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/3morram7/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the floating.
[Css clear property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)
Something like this:

```
#cont:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

[See here.](https://jsfiddle.net/8kobmxL6/)

Answer (score 0):

Floated divs will not let the main div to grow according to the childs.add an additional div to maintain the main divs height.

```
<div id ="cont">
    <div class ="box" > box1 </div>
    <div class ="box" > box2 </div>
    <div class ="box" > box3 </div>
    <div class ="clrfx" > </div>
</div>
<div id="foo"> footer </div>
```

and the css for new div

```
.clrfx{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Display:inline-block` property in your box

```css
#cont{
width:950px;
border:1px solid red; 
float:left;
}
.box{
    width:300px;
     height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:orange;
       float:left;  
       display:inline-block;
}
#foo{
    width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id ="cont">
    <div class ="box" > box1 </div>
    <div class ="box" > box2 </div>
    <div class ="box" > box3 </div>
</div>
<div id="foo"> footer </div>
```